# ArXiv compiler adding additional margin to tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, arxiv

I'm trying to compile the following code on arXiv, involving a `tcolorboxenvironment` which wraps an existing environment like `quote` in a `tcolorbox`:

```latex
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcolorboxenvironment{quote}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
 Hello World!
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

On my system and on overleaf, it looks like this:
[image]

When arXiv compiles the document, it looks like this, with additional padding at the top of the box.
[image]
The arXiv compile log does not show any warnings.

For this behavior it doesn't matter which environment (`quote` or `theorem` etc) I wrap. Without `\pdfoutput=1` (which tells arXiv to use PDFLaTeX) it also happens (though I got a rotated PDF from arXiv). I doesn't help to explicitly set the `top` option variable of the `tcolorboxenvironment`.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on arXiv? Can you compare the package versions?

Comment: A vague guess: arXiv uses tcolorbox v4.32, see issue https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/123 .

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was indeed the problem. I added an answer.

Comment: arXiv runs off of TeXLive 2020 (it's on the schedule to upgrade to 2022 later this year). It seems likely this was indeed the package bug indicated.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by commenters frabjous and muzimuzhi Z, the problem was that arXiv uses an old version (v4.32) of tcolorbox. I uploaded a newer version `tcolorbox.sty` and it got rid of the bug. The newest version that worked and didn't lead to arXiv compile errors was [v4.42](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/releases/tag/v4.42) (from v4.50 onwards there were problems with the line `\NewDocumentCommand{\tcblistof}`).